# How to convert this image to textbox and button?

Tags: php, html, css

Here is the image :

[image]

Now i want to convert a part of it as a textbox and the "Mag Lens" as a clickble button.

But the buggest problem is that both are on the same image but they have different functions..

Can anyone code this for me ? I have no idea to chat.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with php, but what you will want to do is:

1. break that image into a background for the textbox and the mag icon in two different images.
2. create a container (I'd use a div) that uses css to make the background the textbox image you have
3. then inside the div, put the input and use css to hide the borders of the input box.
4. then, directly after you place the input, place the mag image inside an href or something similar in php (in .net we'd use an imagebutton control).

Answer (score 0):

That's not a PHP problem. You could use the image as background for the text field and submit button. You don't even have to split the image. Google for "CSS sprite".

Comment: Depends how you're submitting the form. I would use an imagebutton control which is specific to .net, php might have another control.

Comment: PHP does not know anything about forms. PHP can receive HTTP request and output strings. The output may eventually be HTML with a form. But PHP is not aware of that. And how a browser displays the output is totally beyond the scope of any server side language!